# Keeping a socket opened in a thread, and sending commands from Main

Tags: python, sockets

I need to open a socket connection in a new thread.  That connection needs to stay open.  Then I need to be able to send data to the socket from the main scope.

I have a feeling what's happening with my code is that the thread is completing & closing the socket right away and then there's no properties to send data to.

How can I keep the thread & socket opened to receive data to send out from the main scope?

(If I take the threading out of this, it works fine.)

Below is the code and output I'm working with.

Here is the output from the shell:

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    packet = mt.sendData('somedata')
  File "test.py", line 19, in sendData
    self.mySocket.send(myString)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

And here is the code

note line 19 is: `self.mySocket.send(myString)`
line 25 is: `packet = mt.sendData('somedata')`

```
import threading
import socket

class MyTest(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.mySocket = None
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        #open socket
        self.mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.mySocket.connect( ( self.host, self.port ) )
        self.mySocket.setblocking(1)

    def sendData(self, myString):
        # send data to socket
        self.mySocket.send(myString)
        packet = self.mySocket.recv(4096)


mt = MyTest('127.0.0.1', 50001)
mt.start()
packet = mt.sendData('somedata')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the example in [this post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/18/code-sample-socket-client-thread-in-python/) useful - it demonstrates a thread that perform socket communication receiving commands from another thread via `Queue` objects. It's a rather generic sample, well documented (both in comments and the linked blog post) and you can easily adapt it for any specific purpose.

Comment: That code was incredibly helpful Eli. I spent the last hour or 2 implementing and understanding every line and it's very clear. Thank you!

Comment: I have the socketclient as a member of a class, 'MyController'.  Then I have an dict of MyController objects that connect to various servers.  I'm finding that once I create a second MyController (which means a second socketclient), one of the socketclient objects looses its properties and .socket is a none type, even though I connected it... So, the question is: Should I be able to reuse a few of those socket client objects at the same time the way you wrote it? if so, I'll figure it out. if not, let me know and it will save some of my sanity lol.

Comment: @Coder1: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. It would be better to create a new StackOverflow question for it, with a minimal code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: yeah, that was a pretty boggled question huh.  I posted the follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282216/multiple-threaded-socket-connections-queues   ..thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

When a Thread's run method exits, the thread dies.  So after `mt.start()` your thread will only exist for a short time.  `mt.sendData()` is being called on your main thread as well.  You'll need to loop in the run() method to keep the socket open, and use a mechanism such as a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html?highlight=queue) to pass work to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Race condition there!

You are trying to send data before the socket is created, that's why it's still `None`.

You should do some kind of *rendevouz* with the main thread so it only calls the sendData after the socket is created and listening.