# Multiple threaded socket connections/queues

Tags: python

SocketClientThread Reference: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/18/code-sample-socket-client-thread-in-python/

Eli provided this generic example of how to manage a socket client inside a thread, and communicate to the main scope with the Queue module. (thanks again Eli!)

One thread works great, but I'm trying to do is manage multiple SocketClientThread objects at the same time.

After connecting, when I try to send data to the second object, it is telling me that SocketClientThread.socket has no sendall attribute, so I think that the socket gets nulled out.

The server of both 1 and 2 receive the connections successfully, but it is the send command of the second server that triggers the error.

How can I re-use this class with multiple objects?

Here's the output:

```
$ python testmodule.py
('sct1: ', 1, None)
('sct1: ', 1, 'tuxy')
('sct2: ', 1, None)
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "testmodule.py", line 59, in run
    self.handlers[cmd.type](cmd)
  File "testmodule.py", line 115, in _handle_SEND
    self.socket.sendall(header + cmd.data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

And here's my code trying to open up both:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sct1 = SocketClientThread()
    sct1.start()
    sct1.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.CONNECT, ('', 50007)))
    reply = sct1.reply_q.get(True)
    sct1.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.SEND, "hellothere from sct1"))
    reply = sct1.reply_q.get(True)
    print('sct1: ', reply.type, reply.data)
    sct1.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.RECEIVE, "hellothere from sct1"))
    reply = sct1.reply_q.get(True)
    print('sct1: ', reply.type, reply.data)

    sct2 = SocketClientThread()
    sct2.start()
    sct2.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.CONNECT, ('', 50008)))
    reply = sct2.reply_q.get(True)
    print('sct2 connect: ', reply.type, reply.data)
    sct2.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.SEND, "hellothere from sct2"))
    reply = sct2.reply_q.get(True)
    print('sct2 send: ', reply.type, reply.data)
    sct2.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.RECEIVE, "hellothere from sct2"))
    reply = sct2.reply_q.get(True)
    print('sct2: ', reply.type, reply.data)

    #close connection 1
    sct1.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.CLOSE))
    reply = sct1.reply_q.get(True)
    print('sct1 close: ', reply.type, reply.data)

    #close connection 2
    sct2.cmd_q.put(ClientCommand(ClientCommand.CLOSE))
    reply = sct2.reply_q.get(True)
    print('sct2 close: ', reply.type, reply.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you've found a bug in the sample code :-) The bug happens only when more than one thread is created at the same time, as you noted. It's because the `Queue.Queue()` default argument is only constructed once when the class is defined - quite a common bug in Python actually, but usually happens with lists.

I have updated the post, but the change is here:

```
def __init__(self, cmd_q=None, reply_q=None):
    super(SocketClientThread, self).__init__()
    self.cmd_q = cmd_q or Queue.Queue()
    self.reply_q = reply_q or Queue.Queue()
    self.alive = threading.Event()
    self.alive.set()
    self.socket = None

    self.handlers = {
        ClientCommand.CONNECT: self._handle_CONNECT,
        ClientCommand.CLOSE: self._handle_CLOSE,
        ClientCommand.SEND: self._handle_SEND,
        ClientCommand.RECEIVE: self._handle_RECEIVE,
    }
```

Note how the queues are initialized now - it's a common idiom to avoid the mutable default argument gotcha.

Your sample code works for me now

---

P.S. On my Windows machine I must specify the host (even if it's `localhost`) in the client to successfully connect.

Comment: I can not thank you enough. I confirmed my sockets & queues are all working as expected now. The way the Queues were created came to mind, but I couldn't make sense of how that would kill the socket.  I see they were sharing the same queue objects.  Thank you!

Comment: @Coder1: yep, so the other thread got the request to kill the socket meant for the first one, and killed its own socket but then got a request to send/receive...

Comment: Shouldn't I just be able to call mysocketclientthread.join() from its parent object to terminate the thread? i've tried both that, and adding a queue handler for join.  the app hangs and it seems the parent object is getting unset.  maybe not a good topic for a comment again.

Comment: It looks like if I startup only one object, I can terminate it with join just fine.  It's when I have 2 open that it will hang when I attempt to terminate.

Comment: @Coder1: please send me an email if you have more problems with that code

Answer (score 0):

For multi-threaded programming using sockets for communication between threads/processes I would recommend trying [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). It makes asynchronous I/O easy and has automatic queuing built-in. Having multiple threads send messages to the GUI thread at the same time is trivial and the messages are queued and handled as they arrive. I hope this helps.