# Python select.select monitoring sockets in separate threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is it allowed to create connections in separate threds, and than put them in select input list, and then call `select.select(input_list, [], [])` from main thread if except that call main thread do not use these connections?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible.
Check out these (related) posts for more details: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273297/keeping-a-socket-opened-in-a-thread-and-sending-commands-from-main), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282216/multiple-threaded-socket-connections-queues).